# Code runs first time, second time 'out of range' error referencing Workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Access DB running a VBA script, calling an Excel workbook to run some fixes before it's used as a linked table.

It works the first time the script is run from a freshly opened Access.

The second time I get

> 'Run-time error '9', Subscript out of range'

The script fails on:

```
Workbooks("Overview Tracker.xlsb").Activate
```

In the IF THEN Sub, testProcessed()
(I put that line in to see if activating the Workbook first would help, but it doesn't. It fails on that line or the next which is the IF line.)

The script runs in this order.
1. Open the Excel workbook
2. Test if processed already or not (check for a cell's content)
3. If processed then pop up a message then quit the Excel workbook
4. If not then run the processing then quit the Excel workbook

```vb
Public Function OpenExcelFixer1()
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
xlApp.Visible = True
xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
xlApp.Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\....\Overview tracker.xlsb", UpdateLinks:= _
3
Call testProcessed
xlApp.Quit
End Function


Public Sub alreadyDone()
MsgBox "This file has already been processed", vbExclamation, "Overview Tracker already fixed"
Excel.Application.Quit
End Sub


Public Sub fixProcess()
ActiveWorkbook.Save
Sheets("OVERVIEW").Select
Rows("1:1").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
Columns("A:I").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
Columns("Q:X").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "[$-F800]dddd, mmmm dd, yyyy"
Sheets("SHIPPING").Select
Rows("1:1").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
Columns("A:I").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
Columns("Q:X").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "[$-F800]dddd, mmmm dd, yyyy"
Sheets("Dell Update").Select
Range("G1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "PROCESSED"
ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWorkbook.Close
Excel.Application.Quit        
End Sub


Public Sub testProcessed()
Workbooks("Overview Tracker.xlsb").Activate
If Workbooks("Overview Tracker.xlsb").Sheets("Update").Range("G1").Value = "PROCESSED" Then
 Call alreadyDone
Else
 Call fixProcess
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you positive that the second time the script is run that the `Overview Tracker` workbook is open?

Comment: In `OpenExcelFixer1` you're creating a new instance of Excel, then opening the workbook in that instance. Why do that ? Your other code has no access to that new instance, or to the workbook opened in that instance, unless you were to pass in a reference to `xlApp`.

Comment: hi, yes the second time definitely opens up the excel file, i see it open up.

Comment: Tim, I'm not sure i understand, if I don't create the instance the code doesn't run ?

Answer (score 1):

Both `alreadyDone` and `fixProcess` are closing excel.  Try moving testProcessed into the main sub and remove `Excel.Application.Quit` from both `alreadyDone` and `fixProcess` subs.

---

**Edit**

Excel doesn't 'pass' the instance of the application you open in the main sub to the other subs.  You can explicitly call the sheet in the other subs which makes Excel do the heavy lifting or you must pass the instance as a variable into a function.  You can also reorganize the code all into one sub and it would work just fine.  For example:

```
Public Function OpenExcelFixer1()
  Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
  Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
  xlApp.Visible = True
  xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
  xlApp.Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\....\Overview tracker.xlsb", UpdateLinks:=3

  Workbooks("Overview Tracker.xlsb").Activate

  If Workbooks("Overview Tracker.xlsb").Sheets("Update").Range("G1").Value = "PROCESSED" Then
    MsgBox "This file has already been processed", vbExclamation, "Overview Tracker already fixed"
  Else
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    Sheets("OVERVIEW").Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Columns("A:I").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
    Columns("Q:X").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "[$-F800]dddd, mmmm dd, yyyy"
    Sheets("SHIPPING").Select
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Columns("A:I").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
    Columns("Q:X").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "[$-F800]dddd, mmmm dd, yyyy"
    Sheets("Dell Update").Select
    Range("G1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "PROCESSED"
  End If

  ActiveWorkbook.Save
  ActiveWorkbook.Close
  xlApp.Quit
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for the input, I did move the routine but it was still failing.  I just had some Saturday morning insight and tried something !  instead of trying to reference the Excel workbook explicitly, I tried this instead:  If xlApp.Sheets("Update").Range("G1").Value = "PROCESSED" Then --  This works !   I can run the routine over and over with no more fails.!   I don't know why VB loses the reference to the file otherwise, but it seems to.   Oh, I also added Set xlApp = Nothing to the end of the routine.  That probably cleans up a bit, but it still didn't fix the issue.  Anyway, Thanks all.

Comment: @Adam I'm glad you found a solution.  I've edited my answer with a little more detail as to why the original code wouldn't work reliably.

Comment: hi Portland Runner, many thanks for that explanation and code.  That helps me understand a LOT!  my script is now working smoothly! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This answer may provide some extra details:
http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;319832

Your solution to include xlApp to specify the exact object you are trying to reference is required because with two instances of Excel open, it gets confused when you try to issue a command like Workbooks(..).Sheets(...) because there are essentially two different Workbooks objects in memory.

I ran into the same problem with programming between Word and Excel (automation) when using the Range object. Had to be a little more specific than that, because both Word and Excel have a Range object.